# Dead lock error in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, deadlock

Ocassionaly, got an error while executing PostgreSQL query:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
 Detail: Process 6805 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1985349; blocked by process 30535.
Process 30535 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1985351; blocked by process 6805.
 Hint: See server log for query details.
 Where: while inserting index tuple (19357,14) in relation "item_itemid_itemversion_ukey"
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366) [postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.2.22.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.22.Final-redhat-1]
... 99 more
```

What can be the reason for the error?

**Edit**

Got more information from the log file:

```
2018-06-29 11:16:10 UTC:10.120.40.41(54058):iwidgetarchive@iwidgetarchive_migration:[28533]:ERROR: deadlock detected
2018-06-29 11:16:10 UTC:10.120.40.41(54058):iwidgetarchive@iwidgetarchive_migration:[28533]:DETAIL: Process 28533 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1997995; blocked by process 12716.
Process 12716 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1997994; blocked by process 28533.
Process 28533: insert into item (description, itemid, itemversion, title, id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
Process 12716: insert into item (description, itemid, itemversion, title, id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
2018-06-29 11:16:10 UTC:10.120.40.41(54058):iwidgetarchive@iwidgetarchive_migration:[28533]:HINT: See server log for query details.
2018-06-29 11:16:10 UTC:10.120.40.41(54058):iwidgetarchive@iwidgetarchive_migration:[28533]:CONTEXT: while inserting index tuple (30446,16) in relation "item_itemid_itemversion_ukey"
2018-06-29 11:16:10 UTC:10.120.40.41(54058):iwidgetarchive@iwidgetarchive_migration:[28533]:STATEMENT: insert into item (description, itemid, itemversion, title, id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

Two different Java threads are trying to insert values in the same table as the same time.

The question is how to avoid deadlocks in the database for concurrent insertion. DB: Postgres 9.6

Comment: Have you found anything related to it in the server log?

Comment: Didn't record the queries

Comment: Did you look? It should.

Comment: I don't have access right now. I am waiting for access, should get it in few hours.

Comment: Got log files from the server. Two threads are trying to insert values in the database at the same time.